# `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair`: abstract types need to be mapped to concrete types, custom deserializer Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson to convert the below JSON to object of a class Npd

```
{
  "page" : 0,
  "size" : 4,
  "leafDistribution" : {
    "D_a" : {
      "1" : 4
    },
    "D_b" : {
      "3" : 4
    }
  }
```

The structure of the Npd class is

```
@Getter
public class Npd {
   private Integer page;
   private Integer size;
   protected Map<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>> leafDistribution;
}
```

I am getting the following error while trying to convert the same JSON in an object of Npd.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of 
`org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract 
types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional 
type information
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "page" : 0,
  "size" : 4,
  "leafDistribution" : {
    "D_a" : {
      "1" : 4
    },
    "D_b" : {
      "3" : 4
    }
  }
}"; line: 5, column: 15] (through reference chain: 
prac.filter.dto.NestedFilterRequestDto["leafDistribution"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["D_a"])
```

Tried to use a Jackson Mixin, but still getting the error.

```
public abstract class NpdMixin {
   @JsonDeserialize(as= org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.MutablePair.class)
    public abstract class Pair<L, R> implements Map.Entry<L, R>, Comparable<org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair<L, R>>, Serializable  { }
}
```

How to map `Pair` to a concrete type, I am using `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair`.

Comment: `Pair` is an interface. you can try one of its implementations, like `ImmutablePair`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, somewhat like `protected Map<String, ImmutablePair<Integer, Integer>> leafDistribution;` ? But I'm surprised Map is also an interface, which is working fine!

Comment: I guess Jackson has built in support for the interfaces in java.util package, but not for other 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some workaround to fix this issue. One Pair serializer and one deserializer need to be defined and used in the object mapper.

```
public final class PairSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Pair> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Pair value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField("left", value.getLeft());
        gen.writeObjectField("right", value.getRight());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

```
public final class PairDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Pair> {

    @Override
    public Pair deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        p.nextValue();
        Integer key= p.getValueAsInt();
        p.nextToken();
        p.nextToken();
        Integer value= p.getValueAsInt();
        p.nextToken();
        return MutablePair.of(key, value);
    }
}
```

These two need to be added in the `OM` definition

```
OBJECT_MAPPER.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addSerializer(Pair.class, new PairSerializer()));
OBJECT_MAPPER.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(Pair.class, new PairDeserializer()));
```

It's easier to use custom defined POJO classes instead of using library structures, in case you have the flexibility.